# Script is not taking systemctl commands

Tags: mysql, systemd, systemctl

I have created a custom service to `{start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}` for StoneDb(A MySQL modified version), but when checking the status then I get this error:
[image]

Which is clearly means that the command is not taken by the StoneDb even I am using the same script to manage the service manually.

```
[Unit]
Description=StoneDB database server
After=network.target
#StartLimitIntervalSec=90

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What is I am missing here?

Comment: Change `ExecStart=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server` to `ExecStart=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server start` and also add at least line `ExecStop=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server stop`. Please read further about using systemd units and stonedb.

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`systemctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html) commands to start and stop a [service unit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html) do no not pass your (systemctl) command line  arguments , the `ExecStart=`  command to start the service is executed verbatim as defined in the service unit.

If that scripts expects an argument, an option such as `stop` or `start`, like your error message suggests, that argument must by included in the `ExecStart=script some-argument` definition.

As already commented:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server start
ExecStop=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server stop
ExecReload=/opt/stonedb57/install/mysql_server reload
TimeoutSec=300

...
```

Although rather than calling the `mysql_server` helper/wrapper script: you might consider using the more native systemd service unit as provided by MySQL and StoneDB as the service unit template:

https://github.com/stoneatom/stonedb/tree/stonedb-5.7-dev/scripts/systemd

Comment: The native one didn't work me unfortunately.